# how to mail configuration in vtiger crm?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

```
I am new to vtigercrm and I need to setup mail configuration in vtigercrm but this error occurred:
```

> Test Mail Status : Mail could not be sent to the admin user. Please check the admin emailid/Server settings

Comment: I am also facing similar issue...

Answer (score 2):

can you please go to below file 
modules\Emails\class.phpmailer.php

go to IsSMTP() function and remove $this->Mailer = 'smtp'; and add

$this->IsSendmail(); this one

Comment: when u online in stackoverflow?

Comment: if u are online then add me divyesh.sigmate my skype id

Comment: i want to Outgoing Server setting but i don't know how to do this i am add all details like 
*Server Name :- ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
User name :- divyeshchothani1221@gmail.com
Password :- 
From Email :- divyesh.chothani12@gmail.com

Comment: if u have any see any mistake then tell me